# Change label text on bootstrap modal before click

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with a label control in it. It is launched by clicking a button and I want to change the text of the label before it launches. The text that appears will come from the C# end of it... but that never triggers. I guess the postback never occurs (I am guessing showing the modal is blocking it?) so the text isn't set.

What I am trying to achieve is: Click button, set label text (the text has to come from the back end), show modal. Here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEasy" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Easy" Width="200px" Height="50px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalQuestion" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" OnClick="btnEasy_Click"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalQuestion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="questionHeader">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="questionHeader">Easy Question</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text="Question"></asp:Label>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text="Answer"></asp:Label>
              </ContentTemplate>
              <Triggers>
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEasy" EventName="Click" />
                  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnShowAnswer" EventName="Click" />
              </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="btnShowAnswer" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Show Answer" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnShowAnswer_Click"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" Text="Close" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void btnEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblQuestion.Text = "Easy clicked";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the btnEasy_Click function, after setting the text value, emit the javascript code which will be executed.
eg.

```
protected void btnEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{   
    lblQuestion.Text = "Easy clicked";
    if(!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"JSScript",
        "ShowModalPopUp()");
    } 
}
```

Write your js function:

```
<script>
    function ShowModalPopUp(){
       $('#modalQuestion').modal('show');
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Everything on this seems to work except the popup doesn't happen. the `ClientScript...` line executes but nothing happens

Comment: does it enter the ShowModalPopUp() function?

Comment: Nope - I put console.log and an alert in there too - nothing executed

Comment: add script tag in your RegisterStartupScript function - ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", @"<script type='text/javascript'>ShowModalPopUp()</script>");

Comment: Got it working using all your code above but replaced the `ClientScript...` ith this:  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "JSScript", "ShowModalPopUp()", true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by using `JS`. Here i'm showing an example using `jQuery`. Bind an `onclick` event with your button that will open the modal. and change the label text on that time. like this way-

```
    //button code    
        <asp:Button ID="btnEasy" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Easy" Width="200px" Height="50px" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" OnClientClick="showModal();"/>

    //scripts    
    <script>
        function showModal(){
            $('#<%=lblQuestion.ClientID%>').text('Easy clicked');
            $('#modalQuestion').modal('show');
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: This would be perfect if the 'easy clicked' text were coming from the back end - anyway to achieve that?

Comment: i think this could be difficult, because when your button will do the post back then the whole page will reload and neither your modal will be visible and the label text will be the previous value. anyway why you just want to do a postback just for changing a label text?

Comment: Pretty much how I saw this happening was: user clicks button, random question is loaded from database and put on the label, modal popup up displaying question. If I put a button on the modal I can change the label text with no reload (because of the update panel) but changing the text before the modal is visible isn't working